# Stata: Permutations of string variables

Tags: stata

I have three string variables of the length 2 and I need to get (a) all possible permutations of the three variables (keeping the order of strings within each variable fixed), (b) all possible variable pairs. Small number of variables allows me to do it manually, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant and concise way of solving this.

It is currently coded as:

```
egen perm1 = concat(x1 x5 x9)
egen perm2 = concat(x1 x9 x5)
egen perm3 = concat(x5 x1 x9)
egen perm4 = concat(x5 x9 x1)
egen perm5 = concat(x9 x5 x1)
egen perm6 = concat(x9 x1 x5)

gen tuple1 = substr(perm1,1,4)
gen tuple2 = substr(perm2,3,4)
gen tuple3 = substr(perm3,1,4)
gen tuple4 = substr(perm4,3,4)...
```

An abstract from a resulting table illustrates the desired outcome:

```
 +----+----+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| x1 | x5 | x9 | perm1  | perm2  | perm3  | perm4  | perm5  | perm6  | tuple1 | tuple2 |
+----+----+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 01 | 05 | 09 | 010509 | 010905 | 050109 | 050901 | 090501 | 090105 |   0105 |   0509 |
+----+----+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Your title asks for permutations but your sample code shows overlapping substrings, the first 4 and the last 4. My understanding of permutations is the same things (here strings) in a different order, not different (and possibly overlapping) substrings. Also, length 2 in your text, length 4 in your code. There are functions in Mata to do permutations, but considerable clarification seems needed here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I agree in the previous version strings and variables were used interchangeably and it was confusing. For analysis purposes, I need to keep leading zeros for each variable.

Comment: Note that `gen perm1 = x1 + x5 + x9` will be cleaner and faster than what you have. (I was the original author of `concat()`, but that's still true.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neat question. I don't know if there's a "built in" way to do permutations, but the following should do it.

You want to loop over all your variables, but make sure that don't get duplicates. As the dimensions increase this gets tricky. What I do it loop over the same list and each time remove the current counter from counter space of the nested loop.

Unfortunately, this still requires you to write each loop structure, but this should be easy enough to cut-paste-find-replace.

```
clear
set obs 100
generate x1 = "01"
generate x5 = "05"
generate x9 = "09"

local vars x1 x5 x9
local i = 0
foreach a of varlist `vars' {
    local bs : list vars - a
    foreach b of varlist `bs' {
        local cs : list bs - b
        foreach c of varlist `cs' {
            local ++i
            egen perm`i' = concat(`a' `b' `c')
        }
    }
}
```

---

Edit: Re-reading the question, I'm not clear on what you want (since `row1_1` isn't one of your `concat`ed variables. Note that if you really want the "drop one" permutations, then just remove one variable from the `concat` call. This is because "n permute n" is the same as "n permute n-1". That is, there are 6 3-item permutations of 3 items. There are also 6 2-item permutations of 3 items. So

```
egen perm`i' = concat(`a' `b')
```

Comment: The `concat()` function of `egen` takes variable names, not literal strings. If you want to concatenate literal strings, you just add them. More generally `concat()` offers no gain over string addition in many cases. Its main role is decoding on the fly of numeric variables and punctuation systematically.

Comment: Oh, OK. Here the macros are variable names, aren't they? I just can't get Stata "macro quotes" to show up inside Markdown inline code blocks so I used regualr quotes. OP can replace `concat` with string addition, I was just following his approach (and didn't really know the difference :) ).

Comment: I've wrestled with that too. I've used the only solution I know, edit your last line to correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks both for your contribution, the proposed solution works perfectly! I have edited the code accordingly, was my mistake when I adjusted the example for the SO.